# how to resolve minikube start error : This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory

Tags: kubernetes, virtualization, minikube

- minikube v1.25.1 on Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language 10.0.19043 Build 19043

  - MINIKUBE_HOME=C:\os\minikube\Minikube
- Automatically selected the virtualbox driver
- Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
- Creating virtualbox VM (CPUs=2, Memory=4000MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
  ! StartHost failed, but will try again: creating host: create: precreate: This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory
- Creating virtualbox VM (CPUs=2, Memory=4000MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
- Failed to start virtualbox VM. Running "minikube delete" may fix it: creating host: create: precreate: This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory

X Exiting due to HOST_VIRT_UNAVAILABLE: Failed to start host: creating host: create: precreate: This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory

- Suggestion: Virtualization support is disabled on your computer. If you are running minikube within a VM, try '--driver=docker'. Otherwise, consult your systems BIOS manual for how to enable virtualization.
- Related issues:

  - https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3900
  - https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/4730

Answer (score 33):

Try this command - It will work. I faced the similar issue on my Laptop.
Tried multiple ways to resolve this issue however nothing has worked for me.
Also, the error message states that VT-X/AMD-V should be enabled in BIOS which is mandatory but this cannot be found in my BIOS settings.
I tried the below command to resolve this issue and the minikube started normally.

**minikube start --no-vtx-check**

Refer this thread:
https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032

Comment: In my case even if it was enabled it was giving this error

Comment: In my case not enabled VT-X/AMD-V, work with minikube start --no-vtx-check and minikube start --driver=docker, I have used the last because is recommend by official documentation https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/ , thanks.

Comment: this is excellences!!

Answer (score 20):

I'm used a Dell Inspirion 7000 with windows 10 and the option below work for me:

```
minikube start --driver=virtualbox --no-vtx-check
```

Answer (score 4):

I used to have this same problem.
It can be caused by WSL 2 messing things up, because it uses Microsoft Hyper-V, which does not play nicely with VirtualBox.

This is because using WSL 2, and subsequently, Hyper-V, puts your whole computer under a VM, and so, VT-X/AMD-v doesn't work.

If you have WSL 2, try disabling it just for this purpose.
Or just use the Docker driver instead of the VirtualBox/VMWare driver.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Windows, this problem usually arises if you have Docker Desktop installed with WSL2. A VM driver will not work since it would require virtualization that is in conflict with WSL2. So you either use the built-in Kubernetes feature of Docker Desktop or start minikube without checking for virtualization.

To use the built-in feature of Kubernetes in Docker Desktop:

```
Run Docker Desktop => Go to the system tray, right-click and open settings, go to the Kubernetes tab and check Enable Kubernetes option.
```

To start minikube without checking if virtualization is enabled:

```
minikube start --no-vtx-check
```

Answer (score 2):

**A. This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory**

`minikube start --driver=virtualbox --no-vtx-check`

Note:

a. For above we must have virtualbox installed in the system

**B. via Docker**

`minikube start --driver=docker`

**C. via Hyperv**

`minikube start --driver=hyperv`

Answer (score 1):

Use **minikube start --driver=docker** as an alternative,

But your issue might resolve if you **minikube start --driver=virtualbox --no-vtx-check**

Note: to use virtualbox as driver to minikube, **VT-X/AMD-v** should be enabled at BIOS level.

Answer (score 0):

**I faced the same problem, the solution is:**

- Uninstall WLS (If it is installed)
- Disable Hyper-V Feature
- Disable WLS Feature

Disabling Hyper-V
[Disable Hyper-V Feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSnRR.png)

Disabling WLS:
[Disable WLS Feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO7aT.png)

Testing
[Creating Minikube cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jcii.png)

Answer (score -1):

Those "VT-X/AMD-v" are instructions that need to be enabled, nowadays, running virtualization software such as VirtualBox.

Short answer: as suggested by the error message, those instructions are unavailable. Either because the hardware is just too old, or most likely because those instructions were disabled in your BIOS.

In the latter case, reboot your computer and enter the BIOS. Dig through your BIOS menus, look for CPU options, something about VT-X, AMD-v, virtualization instructions, ... depending on your motherboard, the name could differ slightly.

I'm not sure why adding "--driver=virtualbox" would help, considering your initial message already mentions VirtualBox was to be used, while suggesting to change this to "--driver=docker"

Comment: In my case even if it was enabled it was giving this error.

Answer (score -2):

I struggled with above error on Windows 10 (Lenovo Ideapad). Finally, when I ran this command:

```sh
minikube start --driver=virtualbox
```

It worked in one go and created the `minikube` machine in my VirtualBox.